# How to Include Arrows and Superscripts in RMardown Table

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am new to R so please spare me.
I have a table and I would like to include up and down arrows in one column. I intend to construct a data.frame with one column exclusively up or down arrows. I can print an up arrow using & # 8 6 7 9 ; which yields ⇧ and I can print a down arrow using & # 8 6 8 1 ; which yields ⇩. How cool! However, how can I put this into my data.table in Rmardown? Additionally, any ideas on how I can paste superscripted characters in a column?
(I'm using knitr to pdf in RMardown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution with **`kableExtra`**.

`.Rmd` file:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
```

```{r}
mtcars[1:4, 1:4] %>%
  mutate(arrows = c("$\\uparrow$", "$\\downarrow$", "$\\rightarrow$", "$\\leftarrow$")) %>% # you can use LaTeX code here (just place it like this: "$\LaTeXcode$") %>%
  mutate(superscript = c("$Example^{test}$", "$R^2$", "$R^2$", "$R^2$")) %>%
  kbl(booktabs = T, linesep = "", escape = F)
```
````

-output

[image]

Comment: bttomio to the rescue once again! You have answered a couple questions in the past and I appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome, @AaronSzcz! Glad to be helping